# Yolo merging datasets from robotflow

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, yolov8, roboflow

Combining two data set from robot flow to train custum model yolo v8. Problems in classes prefict

I have two data sets from robotflow one for traffic light detection and other for crosse path detection i want to create yolo model for predect two classes i try to copy file of validation in global floder that contain all images of traffic light and cross path . Problems, model can't detect traffic light,but when train each one separately it's gives best results. Why this problem happen when i merged data??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem but maybe you're looking for the Merge Datasets feature: https://docs.roboflow.com/datasets/merge-datasets

Comment: Yes bro, for example i have folder from robot flow contain tree subfolder training, validate, test for detection of person and other for detection of dog. When i merged the two folder (we copies images of test for each class in global folder , and the same for labels and for validate and training) but after training the model not able to detect all classes. Why?.i hope you are understood

Comment: Follow the instructions in the link. My guess is you didn’t edit the yaml right but hard to know